# Cannot get collection of event from showclix using their api

Tags: python, api, rest

I am trying to get collection of all events from the showclix api. They have listed the api endpoint here:
https://technically.showclix.com/events.html#events-events-get

here is my code:

```
def func2(self):
        Headers = {
            'X-API-Token ': '<1234989898>',
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json',
        }
        response = requests.get(
            'https://www.showclix.com/rest.api/events' , headers=Headers)
        print(response)
```

I am trying all the ways listed on their website but still getting 404 response.

Answer (score 0):

Their API documentation is pretty bad, the actual API endpoint is:

https://showclix.com/api/events